# get x and y axis value of each alphabet in div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, svg

In div, I have text "Beautiful" now I want to read at what axis (x and y) each alphabet starts and where it ends.

Basically I want to do clipping mask. I have tried many ways like http://blogs.adobe.com/dreamweaver/2015/07/css-vs-svg-graphical-text.html, http://nimbupani.com/using-background-clip-for-text-with-css-fallback.html and PHP GD library but no gain so now I am trying to read x axis and y axis of each alphabet in div so that i can remove pixels from image, set it on text and can get following results.

[image]

can anyone give me idea about it means how can i do it?

Comment: What problems did you encounter following the information in the first link?

Comment: It only works in webkit browsers

Answer (score 0):

use a png image having masking of your text and fill outer area with white color as per your example,  and use div layer one has background image and the top one has your masked png image.
it is much easier than detecting x and y coordinates.

Comment: Sorry, As I am not designer so I did not understand "masking" and "div layer". I have searched on google as well. Can you bit elaborate it?